# Set Task type to Empty

Tags: api, soap-api, tasks

How to set the type of the Task to empty value using SOAP API?

While creating Task when I set the empty string - SF just takes the default value for the organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [fieldsToNull](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm) to include the fields that have a null value specified, otherwise the default value will be taken. This is due to a limitation in how WSDL describes the service; fields with null attributes will be silently discarded by default.